# Getting Official Legal Documents

Tags: bankruptcy

Is there a recommended or official location that's recommended to get "official" legal documents that'd be used to file WITH THE COURT for Chapter 7 bankruptcy?

- I wasn't sure if getting legal court documents or forms to fill out online was acceptable or if there was a "standard" format these documents must conform to be acceptable by the courts.
- If there's an official and standard format, are there ways non-legal people can confirm these are correct besides asking an attorney.

Specifically if it matters, document-wise, I need forms to list the DEBTS and the company names, amounts, etc. of the DEBT I'd need to file against.

I've went online and can easily find resources to download to fill out, but I wasn't sure if there was something to reference to confirm format authenticity or if I should go to a particular "official" site only and this would ensure it's correct.

So Chapter 7, wipe it clean bankruptcy forms, for a regular person in America to list the debts and any other helpful things I can complete up front so I understand what I have and to take to an attorney knowing what I have beforehand as well.

Whether or not an attorney may give me a price reduction for doing this is yet to be negotiated perhaps (their legal assistant will probably do all the paperwork otherwise), but I want to have a clear understand of the accuracy of everything for myself beforehand at a minimum.